# javascript url-safe filename-safe string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, filenames

Looking for a regex/replace function to take a user inputted string say, "John Smith's Cool Page" and return a filename/url safe string like "john_smith_s_cool_page.html", or something to that extent.

Comment: Define "filename/url safe string". Browsers will do URL encoding of strings in addresses, modern computers have very few restrictions on file name characters.

Comment: I'd use something like `"  aAbc1290!@#$%^&*()-=_+;:[]{}'\"|,./<>?  ".replace(/[\\\/:\*\?"<>\|]/g, "").trim() + ".html"`

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Well, here's one that replaces anything that's not a letter or a number, and makes it all lower case, like your example.

```
var s = "John Smith's Cool Page";
var filename = s.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '_').toLowerCase();
```

Explanation:

The regular expression is `/[^a-z0-9]/gi`. Well, actually the `gi` at the end is just a set of options that are used when the expression is used.

- `i` means "ignore upper/lower case differences"
- `g` means "global", which really means that every match should be replaced, not just the first one.

So what we're looking as is really just `[^a-z0-9]`. Let's read it step-by-step:

- The `[` and `]` define a "character class", which is a list of single-characters. If you'd write `[one]`, then that would match either 'o' or 'n' or 'e'.
- However, there's a `^` at the start of the list of characters. That means it should match only characters **not** in the list.
- Finally, the list of characters is `a-z0-9`. Read this as "a through z and 0 through 9". It's a short way of writing `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789`.

So basically, what the regular expression says is: "Find every letter that is not between 'a' and 'z' or between '0' and '9'".

Comment: this is really close, how do I add in a few more individual safe characters like `_` and `-` ?

Comment: can i do this? `var filename = s.replace(/[^a-z0-9_-]/gi, '_').toLowerCase()`

Comment: Ooh, that's so close! You're just missing one bit of information - the `-` is a reserved character inside `[]`. You'll need to escape it. So instead of writing `-` for the dash ('-'), you need to use `\-`. In other words, the regular expression would be `/[^a-z0-9_\-]/gi`

Comment: This is not really a full solution. Take a look at MS's page on filenames, there are more requirements involved to make the page safe (e.g., max length): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I will add a `.replace(/_{2,}/g, '_')` to eliminate consecutive `_` chars in the result which are very ugly.

Comment: what about extension e.g. `.png` is valid part of filename right? Here dot is not taken into consideration.

Comment: Ooh, @ShalomCraimer! So, so close! ;-) `-` is a special character inside `[]`, but it's unnecessary to escape it as long as it's the last character in the brackets. This is also `eslint's` preference (`no-useless-escape`). So: `/[^a-z0-9_-]/gi`!

Comment: Thanks @Arel for pointing it out - TIL! For those curious where this was in the standard at the time, see https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.2.16 and look at NOTE 3 which says: "A - character [...] is treated literally if it is the first or last character of ClassRanges [...]"

Comment: if this is a file name, why are you converting `.` to `_`? Dots are perfectly ok in filenames, thus I'd use `/[^a-z0-9\.]/gi`

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain the regex! @ShalomCraimer

Comment: Is the lasting `toLowerCase()` required to get a filename-safe string ?

Answer (score 23):

I know the original poster asked for a simple Regular Expression, however, there is more involved in sanitizing filenames, including filename length, reserved filenames, and, of course reserved characters.

Take a look at the [code in node-sanitize-filename](https://github.com/parshap/node-sanitize-filename/blob/master/index.js) for a more robust solution.

Comment: When they do `truncate` at the end, wouldn't that cut the extension file name? ex: .jpg

Comment: they truncate to get under 255 chars which is a limitation in some filesystems. It'd only truncate the extension if the filename was already too long

Answer (score 7):

For more flexible and robust handling of unicode characters etc, you could use the [slugify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify) in conjunction with some regex to remove [unsafe URL characters](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/)

```
const urlSafeFilename = slugify(filename, { remove: /"<>#%\{\}\|\\\^~\[\]`;\?:@=&/g });
```

This produces nice kebab-case filenemas in your url and allows for more characters outside the `a-z0-9` range.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did. It works to convert full sentences into a decently clean URL.

First it trims the string, then it converts spaces to dashes (-), then it gets rid of anything that's not a letter/number/dash

```js
function slugify(title) {
  return title
    .trim()
    .replace(/ +/g, '-')
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/[^a-z0-9-]/g, '')
}

slug.value = slugify(text.value);
text.oninput = () => { slug.value = slugify(text.value); };
```

```html
<input id="text" value="Foo: the old @Foobîdoo!!  " style="font-size:1.2em">

<input id="slug" readonly style="font-size:1.2em">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirement is to replaces white spaces and aphostophy `s with _ and append the .html at the end try to find such regex.

refer

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: That string was just an example, but ultimately looking for something that would replace ALL non safe characters. basically anything that's not filename safe.. [a-z][A-Z][0-9]["_","-"]