# Sanitizing string to make it URL and filename safe?

Tags: javascript

I need javascript to create the exact same url-safe filename as I have created in PHP.

This is my code in PHP:

```
<?php
$clean_name = strtr($string, 'ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ', 'SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyy');
$clean_name = strtr($clean_name, array('Þ' => 'TH', 'þ' => 'th', 'Ð' => 'DH', 'ð' => 'dh', 'ß' => 'ss', 'Œ' => 'OE', 'œ' => 'oe', 'Æ' => 'AE', 'æ' => 'ae', 'µ' => 'u'));

$clean_name = preg_replace(array('/\s/', '/\.[\.]+/', '/[^\w_\.\-]/'), array('_', '.', ''), $clean_name);
$clean_name = strtolower($clean_name);

?>
```

How would I replicate that in Javascript?

Comment: Did you find the matching functions in Javascript corresponding to those used in PHP?

Comment: Similar Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485027/javascript-url-safe-filename-safe-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your PHP-value in a javascript value like this:

```
<script>

var JSvar = "<?= $phpVar ?>";

</script>
```