# add hyphen (-) automatically after each word with javascript

Tags: javascript

i am using a form with two inputs. When you type in the first input, the text is automatically copied to the second input, via javascript. Now I would like the second input to automatically add a dash (-) after each word. To understand this better, I would like to replace the space between one word and another with -.
Unfortunately I don't know how to do it, can someone help me ?. The javascript code I am using to copy from one input to another is as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#textBox1').on('change', function() {
   $('#textBox2').val($(this).val());
 }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$(this).val().replace(/ /g, '-')`, for real-time change in the second input you can use `input` instead of `change`

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: @pilchard I take this opportunity to ask you. Is it possible to remove commas and periods from the copied input?

Comment: it seems you might be looking for something like this: [javascript url-safe filename-safe string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485027/javascript-url-safe-filename-safe-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replaceAll` method to replace all occurrences of `' '` with hyphen.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#textBox1').on('input', function() {
   $('#textBox2').val($(this).val().replaceAll(" ", "-"));
 }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="textBox1">
<input id="textBox2">
```